# Can I have a "child router" using React Router?

Tags: routes, reactjs, react-router

I have a basic CRUD component with common routes: `/`, `/create`, `/:id`, `/:id/edit`...

I want to be able to attach them to the main application router by rerouting all `/posts/*` URLs to this new component.

I can't seem to grasp if it's possible without having to rewrite all child routes manually. `/posts/`, `/posts/:id`, `/posts/create`, etc.

I am referring to [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

react-router 1.x use history,
so you can use basename to do prefix

https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/BasenameSupport.md